# How do you solve the following error "could not load file or assembly 'microsoft aspnetcore razor runtime 3.1 1"

Tags: c#

Am building an API with .net core 3.0, when I run a build my code compiles with no errors or warnings but when I run the app in my add-controllers service I get an error that says "could not load file or assembly 'microsoft aspnetcore razor runtime 3.1 1".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The more information you can provide, the easier it will be for us to help you. For this question, see if you can reproduce this in a minimal project and share the project file and the class files that reproduce the problem.

Comment: Agreed that the project file would be helpful so we could see what other references you have. There may be a conflict, as seen in this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18334#issuecomment-576882109

Answer (score 0):

APIs don't have (and don't need) the razor engine loaded. Check if you have Razor from NuGet or install it.

You must also understand what you need from razor. It is used for rendering views and APIs don't have views.

Comment: I've tried installing the nuget package, nothing changed. I understand that razor isn't a requirement as far as api's go but that's what's perplexing about it, I am however using swagger to test my api and there's configuration I've added in the addseaggergen service that makes it aware of identity confirmation I've added to the API so maybe there's a correlation (not sure) but the point is I've installed Razor, Razor Runtime, Razor Mvc, no change.